# unable to create flutter project in android studio windows 10?

Tags: flutter, android-studio

unable to create `flutter project`  in android studio
I have gone through various question that has been posted in `stack overflow` but none of them solved the problem.

how to get rid of from this?

[image]

Comment: go through the [doument](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows) it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Run the `flutter create project_name` command